# How to create exe of project who has .cxx .py file and many dlls

Tags: python, c++, dll, build, exe

I have a code who is depended on Qt, PyQt, VTK, ITK, libs.
using CMAKE to build
Environment : Windows
I want to distribute EXE who has cxx, py files and related dlls

I have tried to compile and got executable but my python files are remaining necked.
I don't want to share python files as a script.

how we can make those python files as a dlls

Comment: If you are using CMake with your application have it create an NSIS installer for your executable, dlls and other assets.

Comment: yes using NSIS installer which is creating executable but copying python scripts as it is in the lib, even after installing the software

Answer (score 1):

python is often a hard language to turn to exe but the best way to do so is using the `pyinstaller` package. Installed by `pip install pyinstaller` and can turn a `.py` file to a `.exe` by `pyinstaller --onefile FILENAME.py` in `CMD`. After that your exe file should be stored in a folder called `disk`. The other files can just be included in the same file as the exe.

docs: https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/

Comment: how can I include pyinstaller in the build process,
As I can understand this pyinstaller will only create executable for one file only. In my project I have around 500 files written in cpp, around 300 files written in python.

Comment: @Dwij Mistry Packing that many files inside one exe file could be very difficult, in your case I believe python is not capable of such a thing so you may have to a c++  package. If there was fewer files like 5 or 10 I would recement creating a separate exe for each one and coding a launcher to run the needed file for the program to start but  with having over 800 files that would be very time consuming and inefficient. Apologies if I have  confused you.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NCFuu-HNG0E this video might help you but again it would be very time consuming (This video is instructions to how you can turn two exe files into one, it is NOT the best way to do this but if you are really desperate you can use this)